# Some problems at using python for making thumbnails

Tags: python, image

I'm studying image classification with python and tensorflow. Before classify image dataset, I have to do reform my images to thumbnails. When I changed my images to thumbnails, thumbnails created all red color. Just like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqySl.png)

It is chest x-ray images downloaded from here (https://ceb.nlm.nih.gov/repositories/tuberculosis-chest-x-ray-image-data-sets/). Montgomery County X-ray Set. Why is it happend? Whats the problem?

My image to thumbnail python code is here. python 3.5 used.

```
def _image_to_thumbnail(self):
    size = (200, 200)  

    for file in [filename for filename in os.listdir(ImageToCSV.__IMAGE_PATH) if
                 re.search('[0-9]+\.(jpg|jpeg|png)', filename) is not None]:
        try:
            # print(file)
            filename, ext = os.path.splitext(file)

            new_img = Image.new("RGB", (200, 200), "black")
            im = Image.open(ImageToCSV.__IMAGE_PATH + str(file))  
            im.thumbnail(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)  
            load_img = im.load()
            load_newimg = new_img.load()
            i_offset = (200 - im.size[0]) / 2
            j_offset = (200 - im.size[1]) / 2

            for i in range(0, im.size[0]):
                for j in range(0, im.size[1]):
                    load_newimg[i + i_offset, j + j_offset] = load_img[i, j]

            if ext.lower() in ('.jpeg', '.jpg'):
                new_img.save(ImageToCSV.__IMAGE_PATH + 'resized\\' + str(filename) + '.jpeg')
            elif ext.lower() == '.png':
                new_img.save(ImageToCSV.__IMAGE_PATH + 'resized\\' + str(filename) + '.png')
        except Exception as e:
            print(str(file), e)
```